# Swiper js append and prepend not working with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have created multiple swiper carousels on the page with the code below. Everything works except the append and prepend slide if i remove the code the everything works fine

```
 $('.swiper-container').each(function() {
    var cggoSwiper = new Swiper( $(this) , {
      //swiper paramenters here 
    });
      cggoSwiper.appendSlide(cggowlContentAfterSlider);
      cggoSwiper.prependSlide(cggowlContentBeforeSlider);
    });
```

Please help

Comment: What is the value of `cggowlContentAfterSlider`? As per official documentation you need to add HTML content in `appendSlide` method. Please go through https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#methods

Comment: @DhananjayKyada it's HTML only

Comment: You should specify a unique reference for `cggoSwiper` variable. Because in `each` loop it will be overwritten every time.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada i am new to javascript. Will be really helpful if you could show me some reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the reference from the following code:

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination2"></div>


<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
    paginationClickable: true,
});

swiper1.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>');
swiper1.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 0</div>');

var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination2',
    paginationClickable: true,
});

swiper2.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>');
swiper2.prependSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 0</div>');
<script>
```

You should specify a unique reference for each `Swiper` variable.

Comment: Thanks will you be able to help me with this : https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/273 they have specified the automatic method but i wont know what swiper1, swiper2 in that case

Comment: Logically it is the same as I have added swiper 1 and swiper 2. They are using the loop to initialize the sliders.